# iputils build hangs at "now monitoring process activity"

Tags: linux, networking, ninja

I am building `iputils` with makefile and ninja. `iputils` build hangs at *"now monitoring process activity"*.

```
$ sudo make
ninja -C builddir
log: ninja version 0.1.3 initializing
log: magic group: gid=0 (root)
log: entering main loop
log: generating initial pid array..
log: now monitoring process activity <- stop here
```

How to do proceed build?

Comment: iputils: https://github.com/iputils/iputils

Comment: You should not `make` with `sudo`. You should only use `sudo` during the install recipe ***if*** you need root access to the install directories.

Answer (score 0):

I install `meson` and `ninja`. Succeeded with build by `meson` and `ninja`.

Comment: And succeeded build a `ping` binary. Build process is by `meson ` tutorials https://mesonbuild.com/Tutorial.html.